# How to boot windows automatically?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, startupmanager

I recently installed ubuntu (dual boot with windows).

I want to **boot windows automatically** unless I manually choose ubuntu.

I use `grub` and `startupmanager` (yes I know obsolete). I am running `ubuntu 14.04` and `windows 7`.

Can someone tell the procedure to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, type `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub` press Enter and enter your  password.
- You will see the following contents:

  ```
  GRUB_DEFAULT=0
  GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
  GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
  GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
  GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
  ```
- You can change the default from 0 to any number, corresponding to the entry in the Grub bootup menu (first entry is 0, second is 1, etc.)
- Then run `sudo update-grub`

**Important:** To get grub file in `/etc/default/grub` if not exist, run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install grub2 grub-pc
```

Then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a program called grub-customizer to modify your grub files - this will allow you to select the windows installation as the default boot.

Loading instructions are located at [this Ubuntu site](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1664134)