# Insert ubuntu OS next of the windows7 in boot order

Tags: boot, windows-7, boot-order

I usually work with windows 7 and just using Ubuntu for work with some special software I want to insert Ubuntu OS next of the windows 7 entry to have auto boot with windows 7 if I do not choose one of them . is it possible?

Comment: To clarify: You want Windows 7 to automatically boot of you don't choose Ubuntu?

Comment: do you want to change order of entry?

Comment: @KasiyA Yes please

Comment: Why not you don't want to set Windows 7 to boot as the default in the boot menu? it's easy as that you change order of entry. if you want change default boot to windows7 follow this [How to boot windows automatically?](http://askubuntu.com/a/484074/283843) and if not follow this to change order [How do I change the GRUB boot order?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order)

Answer (score 1):

There is a program for windows called **easy bcd**.

Install it when running windows and the proceed a described in the following link:

[Download Easy BCD for window](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/)

[How to Use BCD](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/use-the-windows-bootloader-to-dual-boot-windows-vista-and-ubuntu.html)

I think this will help you to Insert ubuntu OS next of the windows7 in boot order.

Comment: If i use your suggestion,may my Ubuntu boot loader lost? because I want keep using ubuntu grub bootloader as default. I just want to change order and move windows7 entry to first in the list. tnks